Selecting a few fields from arrays of objects and flattening result
I am using Jayway JsonPath (version 2.9.0) Java library and trying to select a few fields from array of objects and flatten them to string array.
Input:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "firstField": "AAA",
      "secondField": "ZZZ",
      "thirdField": "111",
      "fourthField": "ignore1"
    },
    {
      "firstField": "BBB",
      "secondField": "XXX",
      "thirdField": "222",
      "fourthField": "ignore2"
    }
  ]
}

Expected output:
[
   "AAA",
   "ZZZ",
   "111",
   "BBB",
   "XXX",
   "222"
]

Returning array of all values is simple ($.data[*][*]), but that's not I want to achieve.
I tried multiple expressions but none of them work.
E.g.
$.data[*]['firstField','secondField','thirdField'] - returns array of arrays but can't flatten it. Adding [*] at the end returns empty array.
$.data[*].firstField,secondField,thirdField - this one works in some online tools and returns expected result, but Jayway library returns empty result.
Is it possible to do that using Jayway JsonPath library?

I'm afraid there is no direct way to achieve the desired result. You can create a workaround by querying the length and constructing your list yourself:
String json = "...";

DocumentContext context = JsonPath.parse(json);
int length = context.read("$..data.length()");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    list.add(context.read("$.data[" + i + "]['firstField']"));
    list.add(context.read("$.data[" + i + "]['secondField']"));
    list.add(context.read("$.data[" + i + "]['thirdField']"));
}

System.out.println(list);


You may consider an alternative JSON library to query to result.
https://github.com/octomix/josson
Deserialization
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "  \"data\": [" +
    "    {" +
    "      \"firstField\": \"AAA\"," +
    "      \"secondField\": \"ZZZ\"," +
    "      \"thirdField\": \"111\"," +
    "      \"fourthField\": \"ignore1\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "      \"firstField\": \"BBB\"," +
    "      \"secondField\": \"XXX\"," +
    "      \"thirdField\": \"222\"," +
    "      \"fourthField\": \"ignore2\"" +
    "    }" +
    "  ]" +
    "}");

By mapping wanted fields
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("data.map(firstField,secondField,thirdField).toArray()");
System.out.println(node);
// ["AAA","ZZZ","111","BBB","XXX","222"]
List<String> stringList = Josson.convertValue(node);
System.out.println(stringList);
// [AAA, ZZZ, 111, BBB, XXX, 222]

By removing unwanted fields
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("data.field(fourthField:).toArray()");
System.out.println(node);
// ["AAA","ZZZ","111","BBB","XXX","222"]
List<String> stringList = Josson.convertValue(node);
System.out.println(stringList);
// [AAA, ZZZ, 111, BBB, XXX, 222]

